# Exception when using google guava and google collections at once

Tags: java, dependencies, resolve

My java  code is dependent on 2 libraries A and B

A has a dependency on GoogleCollections
B has a dependency GoogleGuava  r10;

```
Now when i build  my code everything works fine.But when i run i get following exception

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableList;
    at com.abc.Pqr$Builder.withXYZ(ExponentialBackoffRetryPolicy.java:329)
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Collections has been deprecated and moved into Guava. Exclude it from A. With Maven, you do that with the exclusions tag below the dependency tag in *your project's* POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>library-a</artifactId>
        <version>[version]</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- whatever the correct values are -->
                <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
                <groupId>google-collections</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I dont have control over A as its a thir party lib and i cant edit its dependencies.Any other way bu which i can overide it ?\

Comment: For those looking to exclude google-collections:

<groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
<artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>

Answer (score 0):

If your lucky.... include only the most recent version version of GoogleCollections that contains  ImmutableList that you depend upon..

Comment: can u tel me why am i getting this error?Does google guavuas internally depend on google collections?I can remove any dependency i can only add new version of guava or collections.Can u elaborate?

Comment: The method ImmutableList.copyOf is missing on the version of GoogleCollections that is loaded by your classloader (most probably the older version of Google Collections), just try to add that last version (and remove older once...) and cross your fingers...