# Same class different version, dependencies, NoSuchMethod

Tags: java, web-services, maven, websphere, guava

I am working on a web project that has 2 different dependencies being pulled into war file of the same class
(different versions, different package)

One is : 
com.google.common.collect, and the other is Guava API package. When I run this service on websphere application server, it throws NoSuchMethodFound Exception at ImmutableList.copyOf. It clearly is loading the earlier class instead of the class from Guava which has the required functions.

I cannot change any dependency, how ever is it possible for me to override a particular dependency by other using maven?

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try adding an `<exclude>` to the earlier dependency to keep it from pulling in the stuff you don't want?

Comment: I am unable to change/add any dependency/ <exclude> I do not have access to its pom.xml

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception when using google guava and google collections at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191140/exception-when-using-google-guava-and-google-collections-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the WebSphere installation, you can also try this:

locate the jre lib directory of your application server (/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib)
create a directory 'endorsed' put your required jars into this directory( Guava API).

The jars in this directory will be loaded first and override what you have in you war file.

This is not recommended but you can use it as patch to override the conflicting classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do not have any control over the installatoin. Can something similar be done using the admin console?

Answer (score 0):

The first matched class found on the classpath is used.  Therefore if you can specify the classpath in different ways to try and influence what class is picked up.  (i.e. specify the class that you want loaded first in the classpath).  This is not a good practice because the Java specification does not guarntee to use the classpath order.

A better solution would be to manage the classloading yourself in the code.  This can be done by

```
`ClassLoader myClassLoader = new MyClassLoader(libPath);
 Object1 obj1 = myClassLoader .loadClass("com.google.common.collect", true);'
```

Now if a classloader attempts to load classes from a library, the dependent classes would be loaded by the same classloader that does not have access to the other libraries and dependencies.

Note: That if you use this and want to move to OSGi in the future you will incure some pain having to remove this code.  Therefore try to limit it's use or switch to OSGi early!